# Правильная структура gulp

Tags: gulp

1) Встречал варианты названия папок app и dist, так же встречал вариант src и build, насколько я понял одного стандарта нет и каждый использует что хочет. 
Отсюда вопрос, если приходится совместно работать над проектом с человеком, у которого в галпе другое название папок, как избежать конфликтов в разработке ? Не переименовывать же каждый раз все пути и папки перед пушем на гитхаб ? Есть ли способы как то это автоматизировать ?

2) Я так понял, во время разработки, на гитхаб загружают в том числе package.json и gulpfile.js. Зачем это делается ? Разработчики используют один галпфайл при совместной разработке ? Что делать если у меня свой галпфайл, полностью адаптированный под мои личные нужды, можно ли им пользоваться во всех проектах, и нужно ли его загружать в гитхаб для других разработчиков ?

Написал сумбурно, но надеюсь понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Да соглашения о структуре бывают разные и команда разработчиков решает должна решить какой вариант использовать. Вариант app и dist по моим наблюдениям выбирают в основном фронтенд разработчики, а src и build больше встречается у бэкенд разработчиков.

Должен быть общий gulpfile, разногласия по поводу своего gulpfile обсудите с командой, может ваши gulpfile могут дополнить друг друга. Можно иметь свой дополненный gulpfile соблюдающий структуру вашего общего проекта. Так или иначе не нужно привязываться к одному gulpfile они различаются от проекта к проекту решая его специфические задачи.

Напишите такой gulpfile который решает задачи общего назначения и используйте его как шаблон который можно быстро переписать под конкретный проект. package и gulpfile никому не мешают и если у вас опенсорсный проект то сторонним разработчикам интересующимся им эти файлы будут также интересны.
Советую вам взглянуть на этот gulpfile шаблон:
**https://github.com/agragregra/OptimizedHTML-5**